# Guitar Resting Position

Tags: acoustic-guitar, instrument-maintenance

I am not using my guitar for sometime. It is very new semi acoustic guitar and i want to keep it to rest for sometime. So, for the last two months I am keeping it flat on the ground with strings facing up.

I am wondering if this is a good position to keep the guitar. I am also worried about the neck possible bending, so loosened the strings as well for the time being.

I cannot hang it to the wall nor I have a stand to keep it against a wall. I am not sure if it will stay that way if I lean it against the wall without any stand, as my floor is little slippery. My best option is to keep it flat. Will this be a problem to the neck? Will it bend it to some angle?

I would like to know if there is anything that I can do to safe keep it.

Answer (score 3):

Several factors come in here.The strings can stay tight, in tune. The neck will be used to that.On the floor is not good, as it may get trodden on, something dropped on it, scratched , etc.The room it is kept in should not have any great temperature or humidity changes. If it's got the sun shining hard on it for several hours a day, it may fade, and will certainly get too hot. Gentle heating and cooling are o.k.If it has to stay on the floor, at least leave it in its case.You are right not to leave it leaning up against a wall, or furniture, etc.

Hanging up is probably the best option. A picture hook on the wall, with a piece of string or soft wire around its head will do. But certainly not over a radiator!  Or, you could hang it in a wardrobe, along with clothes, upright, maybe one of the best options - its safe out of harm's way, and won't get dusty either.

Most people would agree that actually your guitar should be played, daily, as that's how we get the best out of it !! Even 5 mins is better than just leaving it languishing. Guitars need to be loved...

Comment: I am keeping the guitar on the floor but not the place where anybody might walk into accidentally and i am keeping it in the Cort company provided cloth cover. Will this be good or anything else can be done? Certainly i don't have a good point in the wall to hang it though. I am more concerned about the strings being tight enough to bend the neck (My guitar tutor told me this as a best practice if we keep the guitar away for few months). Can you tell me anything more about the strings issue? Thanks for your suggestions. I appreciate it!

Comment: What about putting it safely under a bed? I have many guitars, and for many years leave them at proper pitch all the time. That's what they were built to expect. Not good to slacken the strings, in my opinion.

Comment: I am keeping it under wall mounted furniture. Its actually safe there! Since i am a beginner i little worried for my new Guitar. Anyway i will tune it soon.

Answer (score 1):

I would add to what Tim said in his solid answer, I would add that you should definitely try to control the humidity if you live in a place with a dry or winter season. A drop in humidity can cause the guitar to crack. For this reason, my preference is actually to use a hard-shell case (soft-shell works too, but not as good at sealing moisture). For my main guitar, I'll often lay the hard-shell case down on a short platform, such as a coffee table, and when I'm done with the guitar, I put it back in and shut the lid. The case has a small humidifier in it. I don't necessarily "latch" the case most of the time, being too lazy. I just put the guitar in and let the lid fall shut.

Comment: I couldn't help but comment on your last sentence. I used to leave my cases unlatched until one day i decided to move my trumpet... Case unlatched, trumpet fell out. Luckily it still works but now I always latch/zip my cases to avoid such risk.

Comment: @Grey, Thanks for your suggestions, i will look into the option of getting a hard case.

Comment: @LS97 That's a good point, it is inviting disaster, and I'm sure that's happened to me at least once. Thankfully the guitar case is a bit bigger so one tends to have a moment's time to notice the contents slipping out and catch them.

Comment: @Grey Indeed. And hey, I don't even put my guitars in cases unless I have to travel with them, and nothing ever happened to mine...